# Phrase for focusing on unimportant details

Tags: phrases, idioms, popular-refrains

I'm looking for an idiom or saying that I could use when people are focusing too much on small details and not seeing the big picture.

A couple that come to mind are "being penny-wise and pound foolish" and "rearranging deck chairs on the Titanic". However, the former doesn't fit what I'm thinking of because the present activity might not be wise. The latter implies too much about impending doom.

For example, let's say some company is spending all their time refining a small detail in their product, while ignoring a major opportunity shift in the industry. What phrase could I use there?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41508/idiom-people-caring-about-minor-stuff-while-something-terrible-is-happening

Comment: Related: [Phrase or idiom for funnelling efforts in wrong direction](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39726/phrase-or-idiom-for-funnelling-efforts-in-wrong-direction)

Comment: thanks @aediaλ that link was excellent, as well as the links within that page

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Expending disproportionate effort on trivial matters is sometimes known as *bike­shedding*, or [*Parkinson’s Law of Triviality*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson%27s_Law_of_Triviality).

Jeff [blogged about the phenomenon](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/03/procrastination-and-the-bikeshed-effect.html) in the context of it being a problem on Stack Overflow...

Comment: This captures exactly what I was referring to, thanks!

Answer (score 21):

> **cannot see the forest for the trees**
>
> fail to grasp the main issue because of overattention to details.

<sup>*[NOAD](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/forest?region=us)*</sup>

Comment: often used in philosophy as example for [category mistake](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/whats-an-example-of-how-the-analysis-of-language-is-helpful-in-philosophy/1187#1187) (fallacy)

Comment: Also, **'can't see the wood for the trees'**.

Answer (score 10):

One word I've seen used is **nitpicking**.

Answer (score 6):

> ***Majoring on the minors***

carries the idea of the effort going to waste, without the implication that there is a problem with perception. Also, my personal favorite,

> ***chasing rabbits***

means going off on tangents, but is less formal and not as well-defined...someone might consider it a [Jefferson Airplane](http://www.sing365.com/music/lyric.nsf/go-ask-alice-lyrics-jefferson-airplane/9558cf5506258d5f48256d650010f27e) reference :).

Comment: _Some_ might consider chasing rabbits an Alice In Wonderland reference.

Comment: Thanks @Unsliced, I cannot believe I didn't realize that. That is where JA got it, too...the link is to lyrics for "Go Ask Alice". I had thought it came from observation of how silly dogs look when they chase rabbits.

Answer (score 5):

Some suggestions:

- Can't see the wood for the trees
- Has their priorities wrong
- Focusing on the trivial
- Wasting time on the trivial

Answer (score 5):

Does "penny wise but pound foolish" fit?

Answer (score 3):

Picking up pennies in front of a steamroller.

Answer (score 3):

If I rightly recall, Laurence Peter called it "side issue specialism" in *The Peter Principle* ([here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568491611))

> Look after the molehills and the mountains will take care of themselves.

Answer (score 2):

*Strain a gnat and swallow a camel*. Getting so focused on tiny details that you end up making a huge mistake in the big scheme of things. New Testament idiom spoken by Jesus in *Matthew*, chapter 23, verse 24.

Answer (score 2):

pedant. For example, some pedant decided that I have to use at least 30 characters to have this answer accepted.

Comment: Pedants don't focus on unimportant details. Pedants think the details are important. Perhaps that demonstrates your point.

Answer (score 1):

I think ' Missing the plot ' would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

When concentrating too much on refining a product, as in your example, then:

*Gilding the lily*

is commonly used.

Comment: *commonly* seems like quite the stretch based on this ngram: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Gilding+the+lily%2Cnitpick%2Cpound-wise%2C+penny-foolish&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CGilding%20the%20lily%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnitpick%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpound%20-%20wise%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpenny%20-%20foolish%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 0):

- *bean counter* (as a idiom, also used in German)
- *not having a **holistic** view* (next to your *missing the big picture* which is imho the best)

Answer (score 0):

**go off on a tangent**

to pursue a somewhat related or irrelevant course while neglecting the main subject. **Source**- http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+off+on+a+tangent

Answer (score 0):

How about using *bagatelle*? From Google dictionary:

> 2. a thing of little importance; a very easy task. "dealing with these boats was a mere bagatelle for the world's oldest yacht club"

etymology: mid 17th century (in bagatelle (sense 2)): from French, from Italian bagatella, perhaps from baga ‘baggage’ or from a diminutive of Latin baca ‘berry’. bagatelle (sense 1) dates from the early 19th century.

If you're focused on bagatelles, you're avoiding the big picture, the hard stuff, etc.

Comment: When you use a quote from someone else, you MUST cite where you found it and use quote formatting to indicate it's a direct quote.