# Adages for telling the essential from the trivial

Tags: expressions, idioms

What are some of the idioms, adages, expressions or slangs for saying someone being incapable of distinguishing the essential from the trivial?

This is close to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/43237/67043) but not exactly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Phrase for focusing on unimportant details](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43237/phrase-for-focusing-on-unimportant-details)

Comment: @user121863: One of the answers there fit: penny wise and pound foolish. Are there any other in that vein?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly the following (which apparently comes from the Bible):

> [They can't separate the wheat from the chaff](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/separate-the-wheat-from-the-chaff)

I also thought about the saying "Can't see the forest for the trees", but that is a bit different. In that case it is more about focusing to much on details to see the full picture, not about getting to the heart of the matter.