# Expression that means something like "killing the sheep to keep them from being kidnapped"

Tags: phrase-requests, expressions

I'm looking for an expression that conveys an excessive risk management approach that ends up having a worse effect than what it is trying to protect against.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an aphorism for doing a self-defeating act?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26877/is-there-an-aphorism-for-doing-a-self-defeating-act)

Comment: @aedia: I think this question is a bit different. _Having a worse effect than what one is trying to protect against_, while possibly self-defeating, is also more extreme.

Comment: Does the phrase in the title come from somewhere/some language in particular or is it just something you made up to get at what you want?

Comment: @Callithumpian That's a good point. I agree that this is asking for something with more of a destructive connotation, rather than just self-defeating (not making any progress).

Comment: One point that is unclear in the question is whether the killing of the sheep is *intentional*. "Cure worse than disease" and "baby with bathwater" do not suggest this. "Burn the village to save it" certainly does.

Comment: How eerie.  I clicked to upvote horatio's comment, and the comment score went from 1 to 3.

Comment: It's unclear if the intent behind this expression is _spiteful_ (cut one's nose off...) or _unintended_ harm (cure is worse...).

Comment: There is a nice line in Kurosawa’s *Seven Samurai*, which is of course not an established idiom (at least not in English), but I think it speaks for itself: "What’s the use of worrying about your beard when your head’s about to be taken?"

Answer (score 33):

A common saying that comes to mind is [The cure is worse than the disease](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cure), which thefreedictionary says first appeared in Philip Massinger's 1624 play *The Bondman*.

Comment: Ahh, this is good, captures pretty well what I was trying to convey.

Comment: @Frank: Yes, I'm surprised there are a couple of "votes to close" on the grounds that your question is an exact duplicate. The linked question very specifically asked for expressions where the action and the reason for taking it are inherently contradictory. The nuance implied by your *...approach that ends up having a worse effect...* makes this a significantly different question, IMHO. For example, *'Chop the branch you're sitting on'* was an excellent answer there, but would be a bit out of place here.

Comment: This is pretty spot-on. *Throwing the baby out with the bathwater* also came to mind, but I think yours is a better fit.

Comment: related xkcd: http://xkcd.com/938/

Comment: Notice that I didn't say **happy 17K**!

Comment: @drɱ65: Ah, but you have called my attention to it, thanks! Don't worry - I'll know to bake a cake when you hit 15K sometime in the next few weeks! :)

Comment: You might say that voting to close is sometimes a worse cure than the disease of occasional duplicates!

Answer (score 28):

["Cutting your nose off to spite your face"?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_off_the_nose_to_spite_the_face)

> Cutting off the nose to spite the face" is an expression used to
>   describe a needlessly self-destructive over-reaction to a problem.

Sounds like a good fit to me!

Comment: This doesn't seem to be quite the same IMHO. It infers a sense of spite, which the OP did not request.

Answer (score 22):

I agree with @FumbleFingers for the general case; "the cure is worse than the disease" is well-understood.  If you're looking for something a little more colorful (akin to your title), ["we had to burn the village in order to save it"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben_Tre) is a US expression arising from the Vietnam war.  (As noted there, this is not the original formulation, but it's a common version.)

Comment: I could have sworn that was from WWII, but all references seem to mention Ben Tre and Vietnam.

Comment: It is of course possible that it has an earlier usage. I'm not old enough to have direct knowledge of WWII. :-)

Comment: I thought of this phrase, too. The horrible thing about it as applied to the Vietnam War is that it made a certain degree of sense (from the U.S. perspective) if you included the unspoken completion of the thought: "We had to destroy the village to save it [from Communism]." As a banner behind a later U.S. president celebrating a different victory proclaimed, "Mission accomplished."

Answer (score 14):

I'd say you're [throwing the baby out with the bathwater](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throw_out_the_baby_with_the_bath_water), in that you're accomplishing your goal but doing it in such an overly thorough way that you end up with very negative consequences.

Comment: It does normally get used with the very specific meaning that action taken to get rid of the things you *don't* want is so extreme/indiscriminate that you also end up throwing away *the very thing you* **do** *want*. That precise implication needn't be present in OP's context.

Comment: Which is why I suggested the same in a comment rather than an answer. :)

Answer (score 13):

The phrase "[don't burn down the barn to kill the rats](http://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=1368&dat=19520909&id=0wIkAAAAIBAJ&sjid=1w8EAAAAIBAJ&pg=2603,3256275)" was used to criticize McCarthyism.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a case of the [fox guarding the henhouse/fence eating the crop.](http://forum.thefreedictionary.com/postst18002_-fence-itself-eating-the-crops-.aspx) There are bound to be other expressions as well. You could also call it a *[Pyrrhic](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/297150.html) Solution*.

EDIT: In deference to @Mitch's comment below (and the two flaggers), I've hyperlinked the word *Pyrrhic*, for the record. Thanks, Mitch.

Comment: You should make [Pyrrhic victory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrrhic_victory) an answer on its own.

Comment: Also slightly related: *cutting off your nose to spite your face*

Comment: @Mitch:- Thanks, was AFK. Didn't link it because I'd typed out *Solution* in place of *Victory*. Your link makes it clear.

Comment: Not quite there: When the fox guards the henhouse, it's because the farmer didn't realize that he was a fox; the original phrase implies that the farmer knows it's a fox and is accepting a foolish risk.

Comment: @Jprete: I take your point, but I still think the phrase is turned eaily - e.g., 'it's like the farmer *trusting the fox to guard the chickens*'

Answer (score 3):

Militarily speaking, the doctrine of [mutually assured destruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_assured_destruction) (MAD), might fit this bill:

> A doctrine of military strategy and national security policy in which a full-scale use of high-yield weapons of mass destruction by two opposing sides would effectively result in the complete, utter and irrevocable annihilation of both the attacker and the defender, becoming thus a war that has no victory nor any armistice but only effective reciprocal destruction.

Answer (score 3):

"An expensive way to save cash"  may get the point across to the management.

"A prodigal safe" would be more brief.

Answer (score 2):

There is a German word "[Verschlimmbesserung](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Verschlimmbesserung)" which I've seen used in English literature (without it being translated).

Literally translated this would be "disimprovement", ie. an attempt at improvement which makes the end result worse. I think this might fit what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 2):

[Shoot the hostage.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ShootTheHostage)

Answer (score 2):

There's the (recent) classic: "We had to destroy the village to save it."

Answer (score -1):

> Out of the frying pan and into the fire

has the possible application of the results of fixing one problem result in worse problems.

Comment: I do not think this really answers the question.