# The solution to the problem is more complicated than the problem

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms

I thought there was a word for this. Where you take a basic problem that exists and the best solution already exists and any effort we put into solving the problem would actually cause more work for us thus becoming a bigger problem.

Comment: Related: [Expression that means something like “killing the sheep to keep them from being kidnapped”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43585/expression-that-means-something-like-killing-the-sheep-to-keep-them-from-being-k), [Is there an American English equivalent of the British idiom “carrying coals to Newcastle”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37997/is-there-an-american-english-equivalent-of-the-british-idiom-carrying-coals-to-n)

Comment: This question doesn't really match the title.

Comment: Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wicked_problem `"because of complex interdependencies, the effort to solve one aspect of a wicked problem may reveal or create other problems."`

Comment: 'cobra effect' check it out on wikipedia

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The phrase I use is "the cure is worse than the disease". I can't think of a single word that is in general use for that.

Comment: The word is iatrogenesis.

Answer (score 11):

It's not a single word, but I believe the phrase you are looking for is:

> reinventing the wheel

One definition can be found [in this online dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/reinvented+the+wheel), and there is a [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventing_the_wheel) on the phrase as well.

Comment: Reinventing the wheel has no connotations of "the solution to the problem is more complicated than the problem" (it just means doing something that's already been done). But then again that's the question's title and not the body, so it's not clear what the OP is asking and it's a mystery so many people have answered. :-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Very true. I've tried to edit the title/question to be more concise, but I couldn't come up with anything that I was sure accurately represented what the OP wanted to ask, and I wanted to avoid rewriting it to basically ask for my answer.

Answer (score 6):

You could describe the situation as "(potentially) [Goldbergian](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Rube+Goldberg)".

> Rube Goldberg (noun)
>   1. having a fantastically complicated, improvised appearance: *a Rube Goldberg arrangement of flasks and test tubes.*
>   2. deviously complex and impractical: *a Rube Goldberg scheme for reducing taxes.*

Comment: The more apropos word for menacing complexity is kafkaesque or labyrinth.

Comment: Goldbergian, love it!

Answer (score 3):

> Building a better mousetrap

The mousetraps we have are cheap, effective, and very simple, yet people are always trying to invent a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe related: *boondoggle*, *make-work*.

Comment: I'd prefer kafkaesque.

Answer (score 0):

I've only heard people use "This adds an unnecessary level of complexity" which is what I think you're getting at, but I've never seen a single word for this.

Comment: The Mythical Man Month.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using '[compound](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/compound)' (in the sense of 'to increase').

For example:

> That approach would only *compound* our difficulties!